# xtensor pass numpy array to function with xt::xtensor argument type

Tags: python, c++, numpy, xtensor

I am playing around with xtensor such that I can use it from Python. However, one of the appeals of xtensor is that it's easy to make bindings for R as well, so write the algorithm once, then write bindings for python and bindings for R, and you're done.

I have started with python, and I've gotten my code to run properly when I set the argument type to xt::pyarray.

```
void func(const xt::pyarray<float> x) { ... }
...
m.def("func", &func);
```

However, I suspect that xt::pyarray won't be appropriate if I try to make R bindings. Also, xt::pyarray is probably a xt::xarray type. I remember reading somewhere that xt::xtensor can be better optimized since the number of dimensions is known beforehand. So xt::xtensor ist the way to go.

```
void func(const xt::xtensor<float, 2> x) { ... }
...
m.def("func", &func);
```

So I make this change, and awesome - it still works. But now, I don't know how to call this from numpy. If I call it the way I did before, using np.ndarrays, this no longer works and informs me that the types don't match up. I've also tried converting the np.ndarrays with `np.asmatrix(x, dtype=np.float32)`, but this also does not work.

How should I call this function from numpy in order to make this work?

Comment: Normally you should be able to call such a function with a NumPy-array. Are you sure that you called it with a rank 2 array (I guess that is what `np.asmatrix` makes sure, but I'm not familiar with it)? Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xtensor-python` equivalent of `xtensor` is `pytensor` just like `pyarray` is the `xtensor-pyrhon`equivalent of `xarray`. Notice that `xtensor` and `pytensor` are different types, even if they accept the same kind of template arguments. `pytensor` can be assigned a numpy array while `xtensor` cannot (the same stands for `xarray` and `pyarray`).

Also regarding the ability to call your code form R, you're right, `pyarray` and `pytensor` are not the appropriate types. A way to solve this problem is to put your implementation in generic function accepting any kind of expressions, and then make interface for each language, taht accept the appropriate types and forward to the implementation.

You can find more details about writing bindings of your C++ code to other languages in [xtensor documentation](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bindings.html) or in [this blogpost](https://medium.com/@johan.mabille/designing-language-bindings-with-xtensor-f32aa0f20db)